# C# - Why am I getting red underlines errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am new to VS2010 & C#.

My this code is giving me lots of red underlines. Its some silly mistake but cant figure out what it is. Here is the Code. "conn" , "try" "rdr" all are red underlined, Why?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;



namespace WebApplication2
{   public class SqlConnectionDemo
    {

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI");

        SqlDataReader rdr = null;
          try 
        {

            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Customers", conn);
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rdr[0]);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // close the reader
            if (rdr != null)
            {
                rdr.Close();
            }

            // 5. Close the connection
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }




}
```

Comment: are you using resharper?

Comment: I Have no idea what that is. All i just did is started VS 2010 and created a new ASP / C # project .

Comment: There's normally text to accompany those pesky red lines. Open the Error List window and read what it says.

Comment: There are 17 error's 

One of them is 

Error 11 'WebApplication2.SqlConnectionDemo.conn' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type' c:\documents and settings\administrator\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\charpdatabase demo\WebApplication2\WebForm2.aspx.cs 22 13 WebApplication2

Answer (score 5):

The code within the `SqlConnectionDemo` class, needs to be in a method.

You should look up the [`Using` Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) as it handles a lot of what you're doing in terms of cleaning up after yourself.

Also, you generally wouldn't use `Console.WriteLine` in an [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) app; it's meant for use in a [console-application](/questions/tagged/console-application).

Comment: I didnt get it , 

The Class is already inside a Namespace. Do you want me to create a random function ? How shall i do that ?

Comment: Classes exist in Namespaces, Methods exist in classes. Code exists in Methods. So, you have to create a method in your class, and put your code in that. See [Ash's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981215/c-sharp-why-am-i-getting-red-underlines-errors/7981298#7981298) for an example of a typical structure.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: Doh, misread the original code, the problem is that the code is in the class area and not inside a method:

```
   public class SqlConnectionDemo
    {
        // NEED METHOD DECLARATION HERE
        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI");

            SqlDataReader rdr = null;
            try
            {

                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Customers", conn);
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(rdr[0]);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // close the reader
                if (rdr != null)
                {
                    rdr.Close();
                }

                // 5. Close the connection
                if (conn != null)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update** Incidentally, if all you want is a try/finally to make sure you close/dispose the connection and reader and let the exception bubble yup, use a `using` block instead.  The `using` block will call `Dispose()` on the variable listed in it regardless of whether it exits scope normally or an exception is thrown, it's also null-safe.  It's just a handy short-hand for `try/finally` blocks for anything that implements `IDisposable`:

```
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Customers", conn))
            using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(rdr[0]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update**: as per your question, if you had a result text box named `_resultsText` that was defined as multi-line, you could do:

```
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Customers", conn))
            using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var builder = new StringBuilder();

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    builder.Append(rdr[0]).Append(Environment.NewLine);
                }

                // assuming you are on the main thread here, if you're calling
                // from a parallel thread you spawned, you'd need to check if
                // invoke required, lot's of SO answers on how-to, etc if so.
                _resultsText.Text = builder.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of   Console.WriteLine(rdr[0]);

How can i Display it in a textbox ?

Comment: @Adi: assuming you had a multi-line text box named _resultsText in your code (just because i don't know your var names), you could build a string and then set `_resultsText.Text = resultString`.

Comment: I am a bit confused , Why are we suing the keyword "using"  on line 6 and 7 ?

Comment: @Adi: `using` guarantees that the variable referenced in the `using` statement will have `Dispose()` called on it when it passes out of scope (exits end of block or exception thrown).  `using(x) { ... }` is equivalent to `X x = null; try { ... } finally { if (x != null) x.Dispose(); }` but is MUCH more concise and clean looking.  `Dispose()` does the same thing as `Close()` for DB objects.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4662/discussion-between-adi-mathur-and-james-michael-hare)

Answer (score 2):

The code must also be in a method, you can't put code straight into a class like that. Follow this structure

```
namespace a
{
    class b
    {
        public int c()
        {
            //Your code here
        }
    }
}
```

Called like so

```
var d = new b().c();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't put code statements directly on the body of a class, you have to insert it in a method, so for example i've put your code for the connection in the Button1 click event :

```
        using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;



namespace WebApplication2
{   public class SqlConnectionDemo
    {

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI");



    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`enter code here`
        {
      SqlDataReader rdr = null;
      try {

          conn.Open();
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Customers", conn);
          rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


          while (rdr.Read()) {
              Console.WriteLine(rdr[0]);
          }
      } finally {
          // close the reader
          if (rdr != null) {
              rdr.Close();
          }

          // 5. Close the connection
          if (conn != null) {
              conn.Close();
          }
      }
  }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You've got the WebForm2 class as an inner class of SqlConnectionDemo. Probably need to rearrange your brackets.